# XSD: can we have element startTag to have either or value?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am trying to create xsd to convert SWIFT MT940 message to xml.

Here is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:tns="urn:com.google/swift/mt940"
    xmlns:ts="http://schemas.google.com/2003/02/TextSchema"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="urn:com.google/swift/mt940"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    ts:eofStrip="&amp;#10;"
    ts:numberFormat="#,###.#"
    ts:rootElement="tns:File">
    <xsd:element name="File">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="TransactionReference" type="xsd:string" ts:startTag=":20:" ts:endTag="\n"/>
                <xsd:element name="RelatedReference" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" ts:startTag=":21:" ts:endTag="\n"/>
                <xsd:element name="AccountIdentification" type="xsd:string" ts:startTag=":25:" ts:endTag="\n"/>
                <xsd:element name="StatementSequence" ts:startTag=":28C:" ts:endTag="\n">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="StatementNumber" ts:format="\d*" type="xsd:integer"/>
                            <xsd:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0" ts:startTag="/"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="OpeningBalance" ts:startTag=":60F:" ts:endTag="\n">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element ref="tns:CreditDebit"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:date" ts:fixedLength="6" ts:dateFormat="yymmdd"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Currency" type="xsd:string" ts:fixedLength="3"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Balance" type="xsd:decimal" ts:decimalSeparator="," ts:numberFormat="#"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="StatementLine" ts:startTag=":61:" ts:endTag="\n">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:date" ts:dateFormat="yymmdd" ts:fixedLength="6"/>
                            <xsd:element name="EntryDate" minOccurs="0" ts:format="\d{4}">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="Month" type="xsd:integer" ts:fixedLength="2"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="Day" type="xsd:integer" ts:fixedLength="2"/>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element ref="tns:CreditDebit"/>
                            <xsd:element name="FundsCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" ts:format="[^\d]"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Amount" type="xsd:decimal" ts:numberFormat="#" ts:decimalSeparator="," ts:format="[\d,]*"/>
                            <xsd:element name="TransactionType" type="xsd:string" ts:fixedLength="4"/>
                            <xsd:element name="CustomerReference" type="xsd:string" ts:format="[^/]*"/>
                            <xsd:element name="BankReference" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" ts:startTag="//"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="SupplementaryDetails" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" ts:format="[^:].*" ts:endTag="\n"/>
                <xsd:element name="Information" ts:startTag=":86:" type="xsd:string" ts:endTag="\n"/>
                <xsd:element name="ClosingBalance" ts:startTag=":62F:" ts:endTag="\n" type="tns:BalanceType"/>
                <xsd:element name="ClosingAvailableBalance" ts:startTag=":64:" ts:endTag="\n" type="tns:BalanceType"/>
                <xsd:element name="Unparsed" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="CreditDebit" ts:fixedLength="1">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="C"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="D"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>


    <xsd:complexType name="BalanceType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="tns:CreditDebit" />
            <xsd:element name="StatementDate" type="xsd:date" ts:dateFormat="yymmdd" ts:fixedLength="6" />
            <xsd:element name="Currency" type="xsd:string" ts:fixedLength="3" />
            <xsd:element name="Amount" type="xsd:decimal" ts:numberFormat="#" ts:decimalSeparator="," />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Schema currently has elements "OpeningBalance" accepts value with starting :60F: and "ClosingBalance" accepts value with starting :62F:.

But MT940 messages may also have "OpeningBalance" starting with :60M: and "ClosingBalance" starting with :62M:. Just like the below sample input message.

**Input Message:**

:20:0006/00000000008
:25:000005XXXXX
:28C:00003/00001
**:60F:C000506USD13874902,28**
:61:0000000007D10001,03NTRF3600009//700007/3000409
DUM Dt Dummy Ltd
:86:023?00TRANSFER?0005030750002?32DUM Dt Dummy Ltd
**:62F:C100507USD21655902,09**
:20:7906/00008000009
:25:000805XXXXX
:28C:00073/00002
**:60M:C100007USD21416405,09**
:61:1005070507C204000,NTRF8007900003//700100/007900003
TES.ID  8007915903.182 SARO 07.05
:86:042?00GIRO?3100000000000?32TES.ID  8007000003.182 SARO?33 07.05
**:62M:C100007USD21000405,09**
:64:C100507USD21655902,09

I would like to know how to mention the "OpeningBalance" to accept either which is starting with :60F: or :60M: and similarly for "ClosingBalance" to have :62F: or :62M: in the same xsd.

Deutschebank MT940 format specification: https://deutschebank.nl/nl/docs/MT94042_EN.pdf

Comment: This schema seems to be using technology beyond the scope of the XML Schema specification, as supplementary attributes (`ts:*`) are used within a namespace owned by Google. This is probably proprietary and non-standard. I could not find these attributes documented on the Web. Do you have pointers to their documentation so we can help?

Comment: Yes, this is proprietary. I don't have the documentation of it. Sorry if I am being stupid, but in general with respect to xsd's, is it possible to have startTag of an element to accept two values either or? So, in above case, if the row of MT940 message starts with :60F: or :60M:, then it has to be OpeningBalance.

Comment: As far as XSD is concerned, the startTag of an element must match the element name in the schema: the only acceptable value for the start tag of OpeningBalance is `<OpeningBalance>`. This question appears not to be about XSD, but about some proprietary extension of XSD, which is apparently being used to describe non-XML message formats. Tagging it "xml" and "xsd" was probably a mistake.